# Querying DynamoDB with unique hash attributes?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm planning to have a `User` table with `UserName` as the hash key and a `LastLoginDate` attribute (among others).

I would like to be able to query the table for something like:  All users that have not logged in for the last month.

How would I do this with DynamoDB?

I have been looking at local secondary indices, and thought of making `LastLoginDate` a secondary index.  But how I understand the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html), secondary indices only help order results for the same hash key, and in my case each user will have a unique `UserName`.  Does this make such a secondary index pointless?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, you must always query by HashKey, unless you do a full table scan.

Doing a fulltable scan, you can look at each and every entry in your table and compare their LastLoginDate. This can quickly become unscalable depending on how many users you have.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Hm.  I'm only interested in say "All users that  have not logged in for the last month" for admin purposes, and so wouldn't need this information too often (say once a day/week).  In this case I guess it would be okay to go with the full table scan?

Comment: It all depends on how many rows you expect to have in the table and your required response times. If you can deal with a table scan taking minutes or even hours, then maybe this will work for you.

Comment: Oh dear, hours would be bad.  Ideally I would like to be able to support a very large number of users, say 1 million.  In that case is it quite possible that a scan could take hours?  Each user might have say 10 attributes.

Comment: Have you reviewed how DynamoDB's provisioned throughput works? It will go as fast as you want to pay for.

For example, lets say you had 1,000,000 rows. If you had a provisioned read throughput of 500 it would take 15 minutes to scan the table in a weakly consistent manner. This is assuming your items are under 4kb. This would cost you about $50 a month. You would have to pay for write capacity as well and storage space. 

If this is an operation you won't do very often, you can leave your read throughput lower and only increase it during these queries as an extra cost saving measure.

Comment: Briefly, in the getting started tutorials :)  I see.  So it looks like it might be worthwhile creating an extra table with the id of all users that logged in for a month?  Then I'd need to pay for that table, but can avoid scanning every single user.

Comment: Thanks for all the help prestomation!

Comment: Yep, another table seems the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can Create GSI on LastLoginDate and apply your logic by Firing the Query to GSI. This might help to get result faster instead of scanning foe HASH key and checking for LastLoginDate and applying logic.

Answer (score -1):

My approach to this problem is to create hash key for example 'userType' which could be 'regularUser', 'admin' etc.
UserName could be range key and LastLoginDate could be index.

Then you can query table for particular user by providing hash key 'regularUser' and range key 'some user name for example'. And when you want all users which depends on their last login time instead of range key 'UserName' use index 'LastLoginDate'.

Comment: "When storing data, Amazon DynamoDB divides a table into multiple partitions and distributes the data based on the hash key element of the primary key. While allocating capacity resources, Amazon DynamoDB assumes a relatively random access pattern across all primary keys."
Having three hashkeys would cripple your throughput.
See: http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/